# cant scroll a list until an element is visible

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium to scrape a page, and got into a problem i cant find an answer to
i need to click an item in a list, which needs to be scrolled to be found.
i found a lot of answers saying i need to do something like

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title="'+dat+'"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(x).perform()
```

but my code crashes because it cant find the element before trying to find it

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@title="14/05/22"]"}
```

all help will be appreiciated

Comment: Please share a link to the page you are working on or all it XML. Not as a picture

Comment: Adding a link to the page you are trying to scrap as well as the element you're interested in would greatly help others to help you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a scroller or buttons on the list that can be clicked to scroll down to the element you are looking for? It might be messy and slow but worth a try.